# Getting data from azure remote repo

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops

I'm deploying with Visual Studio Team services to Azure (NodeJS) but the problem is when files are changed in the remote repo in azure (through my site) I can't get them to my local repo. How can I get it without manually going in and copy the files? (Git pull doesn't work)

Comment: Did you get any error message when you execute command `git pull ...`?

Comment: It says there is nothing to pull

Comment: Have you pushed your changes to the remote repo? You could check the file whether it has been changed through this URL https://<yourwebsitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole‌​, then cd to site\repository folder.

Comment: Yes I push and can see changes there, but I cant pull. It's like those change exist in a separate repo and not in the va team services repo.

Comment: Also check the branch you are on (`git branch`), check the configuration for that branch (in `.../.git/config`).

Comment: How do you configure your local repository? Do you add a remote url to point to the Azure Repo?

Comment: I add a remote vs-teamservices (git) which I push to and it automatically updates the azure repo and site.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT It's a deployment option in azure, to use vs-team services.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume that your local repository is link to VSTS repo and VSTS repo push files to Azure Remote Repo. In this scenario, your local repo isn't linked to Azure Remote Repo, when you execute git pull from local repo, it just try to pull the changes from VSTS repo, not Azure Repo. To pull the changes from Azure Repo, trying the steps blow:

1. Configure "Deployment credentials" from Azure Portal. You'll need to use this credential to authenticate Azure Repo.
2. Open Kudu service page of your webapp. For example, if your app url is "https://app1.azurewebsites.net/", then the Kudu service page is "https://app1.scm.azurewebsites.net/".
3. Click "Source control info" link in Kudu service page. You will get the URL of the Azure Remote Repository.
4. Go to your local repo and add a remote repo with the URL you get from Step 3.
5. Perform a pull action from the new added remote repo and enter the credential you configured in Step 1 when prompted.